# PHP + ZipArchive + Russian language

Tags: php, zip, unzip

i have the followed code

```
  $zip = new ZipArchive;
  $res = $zip->open('tmp/articles.zip');
  if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('tmp/');
    $zip->close();
  }
```

It works fine for archives with english filenames, but if i made archieve with russian characters, i have unreadable filenames. What should I do?

UPD: It doesn't work correctly when i use "unzip" from bash too.

Comment: @Ximik: On what OS and what’s the target OS?

Comment: On Windows XP. The target OS is Debian. But the same trouble is  on my archlinux too.

Comment: @Ximik: So it’s NTFS/FAT32/FAT16/… to ext3/ext2/…?

Comment: @Gumbo problem not in filesystem, same behavior in Win7/Win7 (source/target).

Comment: @OZ_: Then maybe it’s WinRAR. Did you try a different software?

Comment: @Gumbo yes, looks so. I found solution :)

Comment: @Oz_ Why did you delete your solution? It really works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
$z = new ZipArchive();
$res = $z->open('C:\Temp\Temp.zip');
if ($res)
{
    $z->extractTo('C:\Temp\Temp');
    $z->close();
}

$files = scandir('C:\Temp\Temp');
foreach ($files as $filename)
{
    print iconv('cp866', 'utf-8', $filename).PHP_EOL;
}
```

This code prints normal filenames.
So, WinRar uses old ms-dos charset 'cp866' for Cyrillic.
Hope you can change this code to create rename algorithm :)

Answer (score 1):

This method not always works. I've found myself installing an external library like 7zip to do this job and it soves the problem. It's hard to know the encoding charset used for a file in windows.
In my case I had to do this for avoiding errors in filenames after extraction.
Here are my variables:

```
  // Extract file.
  $tmp_dir = uniqid();
  $zip_uri = "test.zip";
  $destination_dir = "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\$tmp_dir";
```

This is the ZipArchive method:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($zip_uri);
if (!$zip->extractTo($destination_dir)) {
    die("Error extracting files.");
}
$zip->close();
```

This method not always worked, but the following does work beautifully (using 7Zip):

```
exec("C:\\7zip\\7za.exe e $zip_uri -o$destination_dir");
```

Hope it helps somebody to not spend hours trying with to figure out the encoding charset of a particular zipped file.